# Convert MySql InputStream into byte[]

Tags: java, mysql, inputstream

I am storing some images in a MySQL database using

```
ps.setBinaryStream(1, photo);
```

where `photo` is an `InputStream`.

When I read the image from database, I need to convert it to a `byte[]`. How can I do this?

Comment: Surely any JDBC tutorial would cover this...have you tried something yet?

Comment: Have you tried `ResultSet.getBytes(..)`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
        File file=new File("E:\\image1.png");
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte b[];
        Blob blob;

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from image_table"); 
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            blob=rs.getBlob("image");
            b=blob.getBytes(1,(int)blob.length());
            fos.write(b);
        }
```

The maximum length of `Blob` type is `64kb`.Use bigger types like `mediumblob` or `longblob`.

You can also retrieve by using : 

`inputStream imgStream = resultSet.getBinaryStream(1);`

as you stored the image using `InputStream`

Comment: Have you actually tried this? With larger images? There is a limit on the size of byte-arrays yuo can write to a `FileOutputStream` at least with some JVMs out there.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is a statement and a result set. Something like this:

```
Statement myStatement=(Statement) myConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet myRS=myStatement.executeQuery(mySQLstring);
byte[] photo = myRS.getBytes("myphotoColumnLabel");
```